# How can I found out were my ROR app is getting its ENV variables

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, puma, puma-dev

I took over a ROR app and I have changed ENV vars in `local_env.yml` and in .env to point to a new MongoDB server on MongoDB Atlas and away from MLab.However, the app is still hitting the db on MLab.

So I also did the following:

1. I checked the computer and there were the same ENV in `bash_profile`, which I have changed.
2. I then did a source `~/.bash_profile`
3. I restarted Puma but the app is still using Mlab DB which is reached via ENV[MONGO].

Is there a way to find out where the app is pulling the ENV variables from?

Comment: Is this in development or on production? How do you start your puma server? How does the start script or command look like? Do you use any tools to automatically restart the app server? Why do you think that changing a file named `local_env.yml` would change ENV variables, do you use a gem or some code that reads that file? How does that file look like? Did you restart the whole server or just the puma instance? In `ENV[MONGO]` what is `MONGO`, a constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing specific in ruby to find out where environment variables are set because they are [ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) so first understand what that means.

You could try to grep recursive

```
grep -rnw 'base/path/to/search/' -e 'MONGO'
```

There may be other ways to hunt them down depending on what shell you use. But if they are loaded from a file that is not loaded by the shell, but by your ruby app i.e. a yaml file , these may not help you. 
 For more info see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from)